# Non-degenerate bilinear map induces isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space.
Let $\alpha :V\times V \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form.

Let 
$$f:V \longrightarrow V^*$$
$$f(u)(v) = \alpha(u,v)$$

clearly $f$ is linear and injective, but how do I show that $f$ is surjective to show that it is an isomorphism

Comment: What's the definition of $V^*$? Are $V$ and $V^*$ of the same dimension?

Answer (score 3):

For maps between isomorphic spaces of finite dimension, injective $\implies$ surjective.  In particular, it suffices to take any basis $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ of $V$, and note that the dual vectors $f(e_1),f(e_2),\dots,f(e_n)$ are necessarily linearly independent.

Comment: Notably, this statement fails to apply to general infinite dimensional spaces (though it does apply to "reflexive" spaces with respect to the continuous dual).  As such, we must take advantage of finite dimensionality *somewhere* in the proof.